# Regex matches with multiple patterns

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to compile one Java Regex pattern but have that pattern look for 3 different matches. I've learned that I can do that using the pipe (`|`) but I'm having trouble with the actual syntax of the regex.

I'm looking through XML data and trying to pull out 3 matches. The XML will look something like this:

```
<Element createdOn="1405358703367" updatedOn="1405358718804" url="http://www.someurl.com" />
```

The regex I'm trying looks like this so far:

`((?<="url": ").*(?=")) | (createdOn="(\d)") | (updatedOn="(\d)")`

In the end I Need to get everything between the quotes in the XML (i.e. `1405358703367`, `1405358718804`, and `http://www.someurl.com`.

I had the URL regex working on its own earlier, but there seems to be no matches being made.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't parse xml with regex. You should use xpath instead.

Comment: I was possibly wondering if there'd be better way do to that. I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: If you have actual spaces in your `regex`, those will be taken literally by the regex engine.

Comment: Haven't you forget the `\d+` or `\\d+` (I mean you seem to forget that there are multiple digits)?

Comment: As stated before don't parse xml with regex, but if you still prefer then [check](http://ideone.com/wTmboA) this out.

Comment: Thanks hwnd. Seems like that would work. I'm going to try parsing it with Xpath instead of Regex though since it seems like bad practice to do it with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 2.

```
(url|createdOn|updatedOn)="([^"]*)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cM1dK6/1)

Here is sample code:

```
String string = "<Element createdOn=\"1405358703367\" updatedOn=\"1405358718804\" url=\"http://www.someurl.com\" />";
String patternString = "(url|createdOn|updatedOn)=\"([^\"]*)\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
1405358703367
1405358718804
http://www.someurl.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have library method that extracts matches, but you only need one line:

```
String[] matches = input.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*$", "").split("\"[^\"]*\"");
```

This works by stripping off leading and trailing input up to/from the first/last quote, then splits on quote-nonquote-quote input, leaving the target matches as an array.

---

In action:

```
String input = "<Element createdOn=\"1405358703367\" updatedOn=\"1405358718804\" url=\"http://www.someurl.com\" />";
String[] matches = input.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*$", "").split("\"[^\"]*\"");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches));
```

Output:

```
[1405358703367, 1405358718804, http://www.someurl.com]
```

Comment: `createdBy`  and `updatedOn` should be followed by digits only.

Comment: @Braj that was just his attempt. He says near the end *In the end I Need to get everything between the quotes in the XML*

Comment: then I can un-delete my post as well.

Comment: @Braj sure. might as well add in the half dozen lines of code that would use that pattern too

Answer (score 0):

The pipe (`|`) is used to find a match that could be *some-pattern* OR *some-other-pattern* OR *yet-another-pattern*.  It's not good at finding *all* occurrences of several patterns.  To do that, if the patterns you're looking for aren't necessarily in a fixed order, you'll need to use a loop.

Here's a code example that starts with the pattern you tried, fixes some problems, and uses a loop to find the patterns:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?<=url=\").*(?=\"))|(createdOn=\"(\\d+)\")|(updatedOn=\"(\\d+)\")");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found: "+m.group());
        System.out.println("Group 1: "+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Group 3: "+m.group(3));
        System.out.println("Group 5: "+m.group(5));
    }
```

(Some problems with your original pattern: You put space characters before and after each `|`, which are treated literally and mean the pattern has to match spaces that aren't there.  I added `+` after `\\d` because you want to match more than one digit.  There were some mistakes, like putting `:` after `url` instead of `=`.)

Now the code uses a loop to find each successive pattern that matches one of the patterns you're looking for.  It matches either `url=...` or `createdOn=...` or `updatedOn=...`, but by using a loop we will find all of them.  (Note that it doesn't care if it sees a `url` or a `createdOn` attribute twice in the source.  You'll have to check that yourself.)

The `group()` method with no parameters will return whatever was matched by the pattern.  `group(1)`, `group(3)`, and `group(5)` return certain subsections of the pattern; the numbers are determined by counting wherever you use `(` in the pattern except for `(?`.  So group 1 matches something using `url` as a lookbehind; group 2 starts with `createdOn`; group 3 is the sequence of digits following `createdOn`; group 4 starts with `updatedOn`, etc.  The way the pattern is set up, not all of these will have values, since only one of the three alternatives separated by `|` will match.  The rest will be `null`.  As a result, the output of the above code will display `null` for two of the groups, and a useful value for the other.  If you do things this way, you'll need to test for `null` to see which value actually got returned.

This would also be a case where *named capturing groups* could be useful.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.  `Matcher` has a `group(name)` function that takes a group name as a parameter.

This is one approach, but there are always multiple approaches to string parsing, and the other answers posted here are valid also.  Plus there are already XML parsers to take care of things like this for you.

**NOTE:** This answer was meant to point out how `|` works.  I don't recommend actually doing things this way, since it's overly complicated.  If you're going to look separately for each attribute, it would be simpler just to set up three patterns and look for each one, one at a time.  Or use @braj's suggestion in a loop, and perform a later check to make sure the `createdOn` and `updatedOn` values are numeric.